# Canvas drawing difficulties

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to create 10 random shapes and have them displayed on the screen. They need to have random coordinates and color. When I run the program it crashes almost instantly. What am I doing wrong?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.randomshapes;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{

    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int shape;
    private int shapeCount;
    private int sxCord;
    private int syCord;
    private int exCord;
    private int eyCord;
    private int radius;
    private int lineCount;
    private int circleCount;
    private int rectangleCount;
    private int r;
    private int g;
    private int b;
    private Paint paint;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private LinearLayout linear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        shape = 0;
        shapeCount = 0;
        lineCount = 0;
        circleCount = 0;
        rectangleCount = 0;
        sxCord = 0;
        syCord = 0;
        exCord = 0;
        eyCord = 0;
        radius = 0;
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;

        linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        Drawing draw = new Drawing(this);
        setContentView(draw);

        TextView output = new TextView(this);
        output.setText("Lines: "+lineCount+" Circles: "+circleCount+" Rectangles: "+rectangleCount);
        linear.addView(output);
    }

    public class Drawing extends View
    {       
        public Drawing(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            paint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            while(shapeCount < 10)
            {
                //Generates 1:Line 2:Circle 3:Rectangle
                shape = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
                radius = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                sxCord = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                syCord = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                exCord = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                eyCord = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                r = rand.nextInt(255) + 1;
                g = rand.nextInt(255) + 1;
                b = rand.nextInt(255) + 1;
                paint.setARGB(0,r,g,b);

                createShape(shape, sxCord, syCord, exCord, eyCord, paint, canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    public void createShape(int shape, int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey, Paint paint, Canvas canvas)
    {
        switch(shape)
        {
            case 1:
                canvas.drawLine(sx, sy, ex, ey, paint);
                shapeCount++;
                lineCount++;
                break;
            case 2:
                canvas.drawCircle(sx, sy, radius, paint);
                shapeCount++;
                circleCount++;
                break;
            case 3:
                canvas.drawRect(sx, sy, ex, ey, paint);
                shapeCount++;
                rectangleCount++;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.randomshapes.MainActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: It is no longer crashing, but now no shapes are being displayed.

Comment: `canvas` is null in `createShape()`. You could pass the Canvas object from `onDraw()` in another method parameter.

Comment: Thank you. It is no longer crashing but now no shapes are displaying.

Comment: You're setting the alpha channel in the Paint object to 0. You probably meant 255.